# How to DNS forward to deep-link (asp.net site)?

Tags: domain-name-system, forwarding

I have an ASP.NET app. The main page is at www.MyDomain.com/Internal/MainPage.aspx

Management asked for a shorter, more easily remembered URL.

I purchased www.short.com.

I set up domain forwarding with masking so that:

www.short.com = www.MyDomain.com/Internal/MainPage.aspx

SO...when we type www.short.com, we DO get the login page (since ASP.NET needs to automatically authenticate).

BUT...after the user enters username and password in Internet Explorer, they go nowhere.

The form is just cleared, and they stay on the login page.

Can we really do this with the DNS record?

Or must we host a new website and do a redirect from the default page of www.short.com?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not. DNS 101. You can map www.short.com to an IP which has a web server that reads the URL, then does a HTTP Redirect to your real url. This is how short url services work. But you can not use DNS to magically have the browser redirect to a path in a domain.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what you want is a reverse-proxy so that all requests for `www.short.com/some/path.aspx` get forwarded by the proxy to `www.mydomain.com/Internal/some/path.aspx` (but not a redirect). I don't know how to do that for IIS (which I assume you're using) but I expect that someone else does.